# 'Anchoring' in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, anchor

I'm trying to build a simple blog with Django, and now i'm stuck on something thats probably really easy to fix.

In one of my views, i'm loading all of the blogposts sorted chronologically, nothing strange there.

Now i'd like to load that page, and add an anchor-point to each post, so that they are indivudually reachable.

template:

```
{% for post in allPosts %}

    <div id="post">
    <h4><a href="/blog/{{post.id}}">{{post.title}}</a></h4>
    <br> 
    {{post.content}}
    <br>
    <i>{{post.datetime}}</i>
    </div>  
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm using a blank url to load the index-page; so this view is reached from http://localhost:8000 in devmode.

Now, if i add an anchor-point (in lack of a better word..) to each of my posts, like:
modifying: `<div id="post">`
to `<div id="post_{{post.id}}">`

Should make every post, in that page, reachable via:
http://localhost:8000#post_1
..and so on..

Which works just fine, when the url is typed directly in the address-field of the browser, but when i try reaching it from a link from within the page itself, nothing happends..

Really grateful for any pointers, to where my problem might lie..

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the 'http://localhost' part. Just use the '#post_xx' part has the href.

i.e., I believe you need to do `<a href="#post_35">Post 35</a>` when you create a link to an anchor *within the same page*

Comment: example link: <a href="#post_1">post 1</a>, is not working. Sorry if i was unclear.

Comment: Are you sure that your element has `id="post_1` **and** that your ids are unique?

Comment: (You've already done this, but...) did you confirm that <div id="post_{{post.id}}"> is creating the 'id' you expect.

Comment: Actually, right now i'm trying to hard-code the id's as a start. Really can't figure out where the problem could originate, since it works one way, but not the other.